# JasperReports: dynamic query string with parameters

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports, ireport

Again a JasperReports problem - really annoying.

Let's say I've got a report with an boolean parameter/input control called *BooleanParam*. Now there's another parameter called *Param1* and which is not prompting. *Param1* builds its value based on *BooleanParam*'s value. In my case this looks something like this:

```
($P{ShowTimePeriod_} == true) ? "cdate BETWEEN '01.01.10' AND '07.05.2012' " :
```

`"cdate BETWEEN " + $P{DateParam1} + " AND " + ${DateParam1}`

Note: *DateParam1* and *DateParam2* are another two parameters/input controls used for providing two dates.

Now Jasper wont accept the two DateParams in the else-expression. I've also tried putting the params directly in the string as pure strings - does'nt work.

Someone ever had the same problem? How to solve it? I'm stuck with this problem.

Thanks in advance for any comments and/or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad - solved it like this:

```
"cdate BETWEEN '" + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy").format($P{DateParam1}) + "' AND '" + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy").format(${DateParam1}) + "' "
```